# slam_toolbox Filter dropping message: frame 'laser'

Tags: ros, ros2, rplidar, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone I am using ROS 2 Eloquent (Ubuntu 18.04) and am currently studying [Nav2](https://navigation.ros.org). I wanted to try the work of slam_toolbox together with the lidar of [RPLIDAR S1](https://github.com/Slamtec/rplidar_ros/tree/ros2). To do this, I run:

```
ros2 launch rplidar_ros2 view_rplidar_s1_launch.py
```

And then I launch:

```
ros2 launch slam_toolbox online_async_launch.py
```

I expected to get `/map` output, however I see an error:

```
[slam_toolbox-1] [INFO] [slam_toolbox]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'laser' at time 1646404216.077 for reason 'Unknown'
```

After reading the [documentation](https://github.com/SteveMacenski/slam_toolbox) and [package description](http://wiki.ros.org/slam_toolbox), I realized that slam_toolbox requires TF transforms from `odom->base link`. However, I don't quite understand how to get the right `/tf`, has anyone encountered this? I will be glad of any help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/397085/slam_toolbox-filter-dropping-message:-frame-%27laser%27/) by [Dr.Modi](https://answers.ros.org/users/97196/dr.modi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2022-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Nav 2 Transformations and odometry documentation are pretty helpful:

https://navigation.ros.org/setup_guides/transformation/setup_transforms.html

https://navigation.ros.org/setup_guides/odom/setup_odom.html

You need something to publish the odometry transform you’re missing. It’s confusing because there are many possible sources for that transform and it depends on how you setup your robot. Here are some examples:

- A motor controller driver that publishes wheel odometry based on wheel encoders
- A gazebo plug-in in a simulated robot
- A tracking camera driver such as the RealSense T265
- the ros2_control framework
- The robot_localization package that can fuse multiple odometry sources such as wheel encoders, IMU, or GPS
- and more….

---

Originally posted by [dognaught47](https://answers.ros.org/users/69149/dognaught47/) with karma: 91 on 2022-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1